# Docusign print driver does not recognise anchor tags

Tags: printing, tags, driver, anchor, docusignapi

I am currently on a trial I have made templates that match my documents, they worked when tested. (The anchor codes have be shrunk down to a small font and font colour is white)

I then remembered that there was a print driver, I have downloaded both the .EXE and .MSI versions of the Windows 8.1 & Windows 10 - 64 Bit, but when printing to the driver the anchor codes are not being recognised.

I saw in their help centre that it would be better to download the PostScript version, but cannot see where I can do that.

Answer (score 1):

The PostScript version of the Print Driver is labeled as "Windows 7" in the Downloads center.

Try downloading Windows 7 - 64 Bit from here: https://support.docusign.com/en/downloads

Comment: Hi, thanks, I did try this, however it still didn't match. I'll stick with print to PDF and uploading